# Use of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

I have never seen the fundamental theorem of calculus with infinity, and this is what my professor wrote. Is it correct?

$\begin{aligned} & \operatorname{arctg} x=\operatorname{arctg} b+\int_b^x \frac{d y}{1+y^2} \\ & \operatorname{arctg} x=\lim _{b \rightarrow \infty} \operatorname{arctg} b+\int_{\infty}^x \frac{d y}{1+y^2} \\ & \operatorname{arctg} x=\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_{\infty}^x \frac{d y}{1+y^2}\end{aligned}$

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this?

Comment: @PeterPhipps Foundamental theorem of calculus works for compact set . It has sense to me and I think is right , but the compact set is the only thing that cause me problems

Comment: you mean $ay=dy$ in the first one

Comment: @AlvinL corrected

Comment: It looks a bit odd to have $\infty$ as a lower limit.  I don't suppose you have that flipped from what your professor wrote?  It's possible to make sense as it is, but confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is going on here is the following:

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus as you know it, we can establish that

$$\arctan x=\arctan b+\int_b^x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2+1}$$

holds for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$. From this point, we don't need the FTC anymore, as we already have established the identity. We can then simply take the limit as $b\to\infty$ on both sides (which leaves the left hand side unchanged) to get that

\begin{align*}
\arctan x &= \lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\arctan b+\int_b^x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2+1}\right) \\
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}\arctan b+\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_b^x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2+1} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_\infty^x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2+1},
\end{align*}

where we can split up the limit as both limits exist separately.

Comment: Good answers that addresses the OP’s misunderstanding. I would have added that if one of the two limits exists, then so must the other.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $f$ is continuous, $F'(t)=f(t)$ and $F(\infty):=\lim_{t\to \infty}F(t)$ exists. Then the integral $\int\limits_x^\infty f(t)\,dt$ is convergent and $$\int\limits_x^\infty f(t)\,dt=F(\infty)-F(x)\qquad (*)$$ Indeed
$$\int\limits_x^u f(t)\,dt=F(u)-F(x)$$ Taking the limit $u\to \infty$ gives $(*).$
The formula $(*)$ looks like FTC provided the limit  $F(\infty)$ exists.

When $f(t)=(1+t^2)^{-1}$ then $F(t)=\arctan t$ and $F(\infty)=\pi/2.$ Hence $$\int\limits_x^\infty {dt\over 1+t^2}={\pi\over 2}-\arctan x$$